# keyboard shortcuts for placing an xfce4 window into the corner

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, xfce, xfce4-terminal

In windows 7 using Windows Key + Left or Right arrow makes a window take up half the screen.

XFce 4 has the ability to tile either two windows side by side or 4 windows one in each of four corners (bottom left, bottom right, top left, top right).

Is it possible to add keyboard shortcuts so that you can move windows into these six positions:

(take up left half, take up right half, bottom left, bottom right, top left, top right)?

Comment: What is the difference between what you say you want and what you say xfce does?

Comment: I know it lets you position windows in the four corenrs (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right). I use a mouse to do this at the moment. I want to know how I can set up keyboard shortcuts to do this with the keyboard. Like Win + left arrow on win 7 makes a window take up half the screen vertically).

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts for "tile window to top, bottom, left, right" can be added since Xfce 4.10 and "tile window to top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right" since Xfce 4.12. I'll leave to someone else to post a proper answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use other window managers with XFCE you can manipulate windows in many ways you don't currently have with XFWM. Compiz in particular with the *grid* and *put* plugins give you shortcuts to place windows in various positions like a tiling window manager. You'll want to install ccsm (compiz config settings manager) to manage plugin settings and set your shortcuts.

Comment: are you saying that the default window manager shipped with XFCE is not as functional as XFWM and Compiz (plus plugins)?

Comment: XFWM _is_ the XFCE window manager. And yes, no other window manager is as functional as compiz with plugins.

Comment: ok compiz is more functional. But you definitely can't just add some keyboard shortcuts for the 4 squares or areas you can place windows into (using xfce as it is without changing window managers)?

Comment: As I said, the Grid and Put plugins do this. I use Ctrl+Alt+[numpad] to place windows on screen how I want (7 for top-left corner, 4 for left side, etc.). I use xfce with compiz as my wm. In ccsm go to Window Management section, enable Grid plugin, click on it, and set your key bindings.

Comment: Passed edit window: Sorry, misread. I'm not aware of a way with XFWM alone. If you add fusion-icon to autostart you don't have to worry about changing WM every time.

Answer (score 1):

See the following setting:

`xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/tile_on_move -s true`

This allows you to tile the window by dragging it to the appropriate place (top-right corner is a 1/4 tile there, right edge of screen is a 1/2 tile there, etc.. ).